# Adobe Flash Professional CS5 compile error log - continuous integration / nightly build

Tags: flash, logging, compiler-errors, continuous-integration, nightly-build

I'm compiling my `*.fla` file via Adobe Flash Professional CS5 into a `*.swf` file on windows. My build-process requires to document any compile errors or warnings into logfiles.

- Is there a way to save any compile errors or warnings into a logfile on the hard drive?
- Is it already saved into any logfile maybe?

I couldn't find any logfile yet and also couldn't find any way to save the compile errors.

Thanks for any help!

**edit:** Since this doesn't seem to attract anyone's attention, I will explain, why I need this:
The flash is compiled by a continuous integration (several times a day). That way no one (since a continuous build doesn't really involve a person) really notices any output of Adobe CS5 compiler. But the log could be used to check for build-errors and if there are any, the automatic continuous build process could inform the developers about a failed build and attach the log in an email, for example.

Maybe someone has another idea to integrate flash compiling and noticing about compile errors in a automatic build process like a continous integration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ant then there actually is an open source solution that can help you to get started:
https://code.google.com/p/fuelanttasks/
It allows you to create an ant macro like this:

```
<taskdef resource="FuelAntTasks.properties" classpath="FuelAntTasks.jar" />
<!--
This target shows how to use the fla task to publish an fla
-->
<target name="fla_publish">
    <flash>
        <fla file="${src}/redsquare.fla" build="publish"/>
        <fla file="${src}/greensquare.fla" build="publish"/>
    </flash>
</target>
```

It will take care of launching the flash ide, retrieving the logs and displaying them through ant.

Comment: sounds really promising, thanks for the link! will try it soon and will report how it worked out for me. do you know if it passes the errors from the flash IDE trough so I can save them to some logfile? Since you gave the only answer and it seems like this might work, I'll accept it :) thanks!

Comment: Yes it does, I'm using it (with some custom modifications) to build swf files using ant and teamcity (a continuous integration framework)

Comment: Also, I have added some additional functionality to the ant code in order to be able to run some functional tests on the fla files before actually publishing them (like checking that all fonts that are supposed to be present actually are, generating locale files, checking dependencies and extracting source code on every publish run), but my enhanced version requires some [jsfl-fu](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/extend/flash_cs5_extending.pdf) and the use of additional tools like [xjsfl](http://www.xjsfl.com/)